# IntelliJ Community Edition for work in company

Tags: intellij-idea

I read through the licence of IntelliJ but wasn't able to understand their license terms clearly.

> Is it right by law to use the Community Edition of IntelliJ when I
>   work in my company? Or is it necessary to buy the Ultimate version?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about software licenses are legal questions and are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Yes, you can use it anywhere for anything.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1584020/685796

Answer (score 7):

According to the [FAQ](http://www.jetbrains.org/display/IJOS/FAQ), yes you can.

> Can I build a commercial product on top of the IntelliJ Platform?
>
> Yes, you can, according to the terms of the Apache 2 license. We
>   encourage developers to build both open source and commercial products
>   on top of the platform.

Comment: You are "quite sure" of something wrong. IntelliJ Open Source is released under the Apache 2.0 License (see http://www.jetbrains.org/display/IJOS/License+Information), and if that is not enough, again, the linked FAQ from 2 years ago clearly states that anyone can build commercial or open source products on top of it. I can't see how you can be "quite sure" of that.

Comment: Nobody questions that it is not possible to build products on top of the Community Edition. But this is not what Marcel asked, he just wants to use(!) the IDE.