# How to open Multiple Gradle projects in same IntelliJ instance?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-12

I am strugglling to open multiple `Gradle` projects in same `IntelliJ` instance without luck.

I tried to open second project as a module by importing it but still it's asking me to open in the same window and in a new window. So If I give same window, it replace the project that already in.

Any one can advice?

My IntelliJ version is `IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4`

Comment: check this link it may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941725/intellij-idea-with-multiple-gradle-subprojects

Comment: How are you importing them?

Comment: @Makoto   I tried `File > Import Module` and then selected the `build.gradle` file. and `Next`.   Also I tried `Select File->Project Structure->Modules`. then clicked on the `plus sign` and tried to add the module.

Comment: @Soorapadman   This one didn't help me. I alrady have the said properties in the `build.gradle`

Comment: You would be much better upgrading to latest Intellij as it has LOTS of gradle goodness

Comment: @SantoshGokak   I am using licence version under my company. Can I upgrade it for free under same licence?

Comment: I don't think free version has any limitation for commercial use. check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583995/am-i-missing-something-about-the-intellij-announcement/1584020#1584020

Answer (score 19):

In the IntelliJ window where you currently have a single Gradle Project open, do the following:

1. Open the "Gradle Tool Window" panel, press "Attach Gradle Project" button on top of the panel (green Plus sign).
2. Select "build.gradle" file of some other Gradle Project.
3. Press OK.

You can repeat these steps for as many Gradle Projects as you like and have multiple Gradle Projects open in the same IntelliJ window.

### In pictures:

**Step 1**:

[image: step 1]

**Step 2**:

[image: step 2]

**Step 3**:

[image: step 3]

**Result**:

[image: result]

Answer (score 3):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791201/90580

Currently in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 you can add the gradle subprojects like so

1. Open Gradle Tool Window via View > Tool Windows > Gradle menu
2. Click on "Link Gradle Project" button (the plus sign)[image: Link Gradle Project button]
3. Select the build.gradle file corresponding to the subproject
4. Go to File > Project Structure > Modules > NameOfSubproject
5. Navigate to main/java and click on Mark as: Sources [image]
6. Mark the main/resources as Resources
7. Restart IntelliJ IDEA

The sources of the subproject will be recognized by IntelliJ and you can use Navigate Class action for the classes in the subproject

Answer (score 0):

IDEA supports having multiple projects open simultaneously (see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/opening-multiple-projects.html)).

I think the issue is with how you are trying to open it. Try just opening the other `build.gradle` file with `File > New > Project..` and IDEA should import as a new project and give you the option to open in a new window.

**Disclaimer**: I haven't actually tried this in the version of `intellij` you are using (it's possible the `gradle` integration isn't quite the same as the latest version for this (`14.1` as of this writing).

Comment: the link you gave itself says `Click This Window button to close the current project and opening the new one in the same window.` Also in `IntelliJ` the project is similar to `Workspace` and `module` is similar to `projects`  in `Eclipse`.

Comment: I think the author wants to open both projects on the same window, which cannot be done by open new projects. The solution proposed by @doron-gold works fine

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible in IDEA up to 2016.1.2